# Поиск одновременно по нескольким словам в БД

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Пишем приложение (Java), которое разбивает состав продукта на слова и каждое ищет в БД (SQLite) и затем выводит информацию по каждому слову(ингредиенту) из состава.

Как лучше поступить?: 
1) объединить ингредиенты OR в условии SQL запроса
2) Цикл, который отдельно проходит каждый элемент массива
3) Что-то еще
Помогут любые идеи алгоритмов/кусочки кода/ссылки на материал
Не ругайтесь, мы только учимся.

Answer (score 1):

3 - программно составлять примерно вот такие запросы и использовать их.

SELECT * FROM demo WHERE name IN ("Chart", "Tabs");